# How do i filter only the displayed elements? (dont filter the $$hashKey)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, coffeescript

Object:

```
    Object
    $$hashKey: "object:25"
    id: 1
    category: "Fruit"
    name: "Apple"
    color: "red"
    __proto__: Object
```

Javascript (coffescript):

```
    $scope.fruits = [
       {id: 1, category: "Fruit", name: "Apple", color: "red"}
    ]
```

Html:

```
    <input type="search" ng-model="fruitSearch"/>


    <div ng-repeat="i in filtro = (fruits | scFilter:fruitSearch)">
      <div>{{i.id}}</div>
      <div>{{i.category}}</div>
      <div>{{i.name}}</div>
      <div>{{i.color}}</div>
    </div>
```

Filter code (js/coffee)

```
    .filter "scFilter", () ->
        (collection, search) ->
            if search
                regexp = createAccentRegexp(search)
                doesMatch = (txt) ->
                    (''+txt).match(regexp)
                collection.filter (el) ->
                    if typeof el == 'object'
                        return true for att, value of el when (typeof value == 'string') && doesMatch(value)
                    doesMatch(el)
                    false
                 else
                     collection
```

So what i want here is to filter only the displayed elements (id,category,name and color), but for some reason when i type 25 on the input the object still shows up, because of his $$haskKey.

Comment: Please include your filter code, or a description/link/documentation if you are using a pre-existing one from a library

Comment: Added the filter code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for adding the filter code.
The solution should be as simple as explicitly ignoring the `$$hashKey` when searching for matches:

```
.filter "scFilter", () ->
  (collection, search) ->
    return collection unless search
    regexp = createAccentRegexp(search)
    doesMatch = (txt) -> (''+txt).match(regexp)
    collection.filter (el) ->
      if typeof el == 'object'
        return true for att, value of el when typeof(value) is 'string' and doesMatch(value) and att isnt '$$hashKey'
      else  
        doesMatch(el)
```

I added some small refactors:

- I changed the top level if statement to a guard clause, which reduces the level of indentation of the code
- changed the short `doesMatch` function to a one liner
- use `and`, `is` and `isnt` in your conditional statement

The main change was to skip over any attribute with `key` equal to `$$hashkey`

This is untested, so I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks very much man! Now its not filtering the hashKey, if i could only ask for a bit more, it would be filtering a numeric value aswell for example the object "Apple" has a weight of 15, so if i type 15 it would bring this object for me (assuming that the weight is being displayed in the html)



`$scope.fruits = [
     {id: 1, category: "Fruit", name: "Apple", color: "red", weight: 15}
]`

Comment: I was playing arround with this line "typeof(value) is 'string' " and i manage to do what i want by swaping 'string' for 'number', but how could i add a plus , so i could filter both, for example (typeof(value) is 'string' and/or 'number')

Comment: Nevermind, i managed to find a solution hehe, just duplicated the line: (**return true for att, value of el when typeof(value) is 'string' and doesMatch(value) and att isnt '$$hashKey' and att isnt 'id'**) and put 'number' instead  of 'string'